# Does anyone know a PDF Annotation app that lets you erase with your finger?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am a high school teacher, and I primarily use Paper by WeTransfer for teaching classes (write on the iPad, project to the screen). An amazingly useful feature of the Paper app is that I can erase with my finger while writing with my apple pencil.

When grading student work that is turned in digitally, I have been using Adobe Acrobat. This works fine, but the freehand annotation tool is pretty rudimentary, to be honest. I am looking for a better grading experience. I want to be able to freehand annotate in multiple colors, but more importantly, I want to be able to erase with my finger. I spend hours each day writing in the Paper app while I teach, and finger-erasing is part of my muscle memory now. It gets annoying when I try to erase in Acrobat and it doesn't work - I have to awkwardly switch to the eraser tool, and then it erases whole penstrokes at once instead of acting like a proper eraser.

I have been searching, and so far I have tried out Notability, Goodnotes, Liquidtext, PDF Expert, and many many more. None of these allow you to erase with your finger. I didn't realize that the Paper app had such a special feature - I would have expected erase-on-touch to be a standard feature across apps. Does anyone know of a pdf annotation app that lets you erase with your finger?

Thanks!